# 2d array of different types?

Tags: arrays, data-types

I got quite an interesting question.
I have created an array of structs, and in each struct, I have an array of address. 
Then I got a method that when its called on given struct [index] its adds sender address to an array of an address of given struct.

Now my question is, is it possible to also add a string to each element of address array?
From what I understand you can’t have 2d array of 2 different types?

```
 struct Project{
            int id;
            string name;
             int votes;    
           address[] voters;

        }
    Project[] public projects;

    function vote(uint index , string comment) public {
           Project storage project = projects[index];
        Project.votes++       
           project.voters.push(msg.sender);
    // now to add a string (comment) to each address that is added to address array 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to fiddle around to correct some minor issues, then came up with this:

```
contract FunWithArrays {

  struct Project{
    int id;
    string name;
    int votes;    
    address[] voters;
    string[] comments;
  }

  Project[] public projects;

  function vote(uint index , string comment) public {
    Project storage project = projects[index];
    project.votes++;     
    project.voters.push(msg.sender);
    project.comments.push(comment); 
  }
}
```

It's not the only way. You can't have a 2D array with multiple types. You can form such things with structs and you can even have an array of structs. So, a variant would look like this:

```
contract FunWithArrays {

  struct Voter {
      address voter;
      string comment;
  }

  struct Project{
    int id;
    string name;
    int votes;    
    Voter[] voters;
  }

  Project[] public projects;

  function vote(uint index , string comment) public {
    Project storage project = projects[index];
    project.votes++;     
    Voter memory v;
    v.voter = msg.sender;
    v.comment = comment;
    project.voters.push(v);
  }
}
```

Whenever you work with such structures you'll inevitably encounter some organizational issues. Be sure to check out some common patterns: [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity/13168#13168)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for, but how do I Initialize struct inside a struct?

Comment: Thanks for accepting that answer. We mustn't anger the mods. If you post that as a new question I'll probably take a stab at it. ;-)

Comment: ok I did that -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60728/initialise-struct-inside-new-struct