# Display Array of struct within array of struct in react

Tags: arrays, struct, react

I'm trying to create 2d array of different types, one of the users have suggested to use struct within a struct method -> [2d array of different types?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60695/2d-array-of-different-types)

Now I run into problem how to display it in my front end.

So here are my 2 structs:

```
 struct Pvote {
      address voter;
      string comment;

  }

    struct Project{
        uint id;
         int votes;
         address creator;
         string name;
        string decryption;
        string website;
        string imageLink;
        Pvote[] pvote;
       mapping(address => bool) voted;
    }
 Project[] public projects;
```

Now I Display Project array of a struct using fill().map() method like so:

```
  const projectsList = await Promise.all(
      Array(parseInt(getProjects))
      .fill()
      .map((element, index)=> {
        return Contract.methods.projects(index).call()
      }));
```

and this works perfectly

Now I want to display pvote[] array of structs. 
So I have created method in solidty to help me get it out of the 1st struct

```
  function getPvoteStruct (uint index, uint index2 ) public view returns(address,string){
           Project memory project = projects[index];
           return(project.pvote[index2].voter, 
           project.pvote[index2].comment);
       }
```

This works perfect in Remix, however when I'm trying to call this method from react:

```
const pVotesList = await Contract.methods.getPvoteStruct(0,0)
console.log(pVotesList)
```

It gives me what looks like abi of the contract, I have no idea why:
*Yes I did make sure that there is a project at index 0 and that there is vote struct at vote array index 0.

```
{ call: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
  send: { [Function: bound _executeMethod] request: [Function: bound _executeMethod] },
  encodeABI: [Function: bound _encodeMethodABI],
  estimateGas: [Function: bound _executeMethod],
  arguments: [ 0, 0 ],
  _method:
   { constant: true,
     inputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     name: 'getPvoteStruct',
     outputs: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     payable: false,
     stateMutability: 'view',
     type: 'function',
     signature: '0x7b76417a' },
  _parent:
   Contract {
     currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
     _requestManager: RequestManager { provider: [Object], providers: [Object], subscriptions: {} },
     givenProvider: null,
     providers:
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     _provider:
      HttpProvider {
        host: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/QqWsfQ60KqF4HCDRrP6I',
        timeout: 0,
        connected: true,
        headers: undefined },
     setProvider: [Function],
     BatchRequest: [Function: bound Batch],
     extend:
      { [Function: ex]
        formatters: [Object],
        utils: [Object],
        Method: [Function: Method] },
     clearSubscriptions: [Function],
     options: { address: [Getter/Setter], jsonInterface: [Getter/Setter] },
     defaultAccount: [Getter/Setter],
     defaultBlock: [Getter/Setter],
     methods:
      { projects: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x107046bd': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'projects(uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        getNvote: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x192e17cc': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'getNvote(uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        withdraw: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x3ccfd60b': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'withdraw()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        remove: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x4cc82215': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'remove(uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        getPvoteStruct: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x7b76417a': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'getPvoteStruct(uint256,uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        getNumberOfvoters: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x870b9dc9': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'getNumberOfvoters()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        getOwner: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0x893d20e8': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'getOwner()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        addNewProject: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xab508964': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'addNewProject(string,string,string,string)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        getPvote: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xb7409fcf': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'getPvote(uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        temppvote: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xbb35e234': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'temppvote(uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        getCost: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xbd3e19d4': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'getCost()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        upVote: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xc99d8eb8': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'upVote(uint256,string)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        change_cost: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xc9bae9bc': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'change_cost(uint256,uint256)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        getProjects: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xdcc60128': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'getProjects()': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        downVote: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xe3ea5ded': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'downVote(uint256,string)': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        editProject: [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        '0xe41c5f6f': [Function: bound _createTxObject],
        'editProject(uint256,string,string,string,string)': [Function: bound _createTxObject] },
     events: { allEvents: [Function: bound ] },
     _address: '0x2b4Ad5532919A8fEB7bB0E555842d893C0b1F148',
     _jsonInterface:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] },
  _ethAccounts:
   Accounts {
     currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
     _requestManager: RequestManager { provider: [Object], providers: [Object], subscriptions: {} },
     givenProvider: null,
     providers:
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     _provider:
      HttpProvider {
        host: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/MYAPI',
        timeout: 0,
        connected: true,
        headers: undefined },
     setProvider: [Function],
     _ethereumCall:
      { getId: [Object],
        getGasPrice: [Object],
        getTransactionCount: [Object] },
     wallet:
      Wallet {
        _accounts: [Circular],
        length: 0,
        defaultKeyName: 'web3js_wallet' } } }
```

Comment: I think you should use await Contract.methods.getPvoteStruct(0,0).call(), also returning arrays from structs is a pain.

See https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12

Comment: OFC lol I didn't seen that. that is solved. Give a answer under this post I will accept it giving you some rep

Comment: gave an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use

```
await Contract.methods.getPvoteStruct(0,0).call()
```

Also returning arrays from structs is a pain. See web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12

Answer (score 2):

Lol seems like I forgot to add .call() at the end of 
const pVotesList = await Contract.methods.getPvoteStruct(0,0) 
Thanks grandfleet -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/44781/grandfleet for the anwser